# Storing huge dictionary IOS

Tags: ios, dictionary, storage, updates

My app has it's own sql **database** with let's say **2000 rows.** 
I know that in future I will add some new and delete some old. Each row got ***prioritet*** parameter that changes in order of user interaction.
I want to store all prioritets locally so my future app updates would not erase them.

So the question is what is the best way of doing that? Remember that I will need fast access to those prioritets in future and they must be easily mutable.

Comment: How about a property list file?

Comment: Never used them and don't know if its allows fast access and ability to fast edit

Comment: please don't do premature optimization. If there's a lot of data, it won't be fast. 2000 rows is not that bad, though. Or maybe use an RMDB, like Sqlite3?

Comment: Why not just this in your database? That's plenty fast.

Comment: @H2CO3 don't fully understood what u said

Comment: @Rob for update I will change my db and after that user's local db will be replaced. Maybe there are some better ways of updating db u can suggest?

Comment: @haawa Two possibilities: 1. Have one db for user stored information and another for data from the app; or 2. Use single database, but just update it appropriately on upgrades. I use this latter technique whereby I (a) if db doesn't exist in `Documents`, copy from bundle to documents; (b) open db in `Documents`; (c) if version doesn't match that which the app expects (i.e. the db is from prior version), I (i) save copy of users old db; (ii) copy the db from the bundle to documents; and (iii) update the db I just copied with the user data from the copy of the old db I saved.

Comment: Rob many thanks! Paste it as an answer and I will accept it.